# How do I resolve SIGEMT runtime error in codechef?

Tags: c++, out-of-memory, emulation

I get SIGEMT error in the codechef compiler for the following code: 
It works fine when I run the same code offline on my PC. I have read this occurs due to high memory usage of `long long int`, but when I change it to `int`, I get SIGTSTP error instead, which indicates a lack of memory.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long int t, i, j, count = 0;
    int flag = 0, gflag = 0;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--) {
        long long int n;
        cin>>n;
        long long int arr[n];
        for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            cin>>arr[i];
        }

        for(i = 0; i<n-1; i++) {
            count = 0;
            flag = 0; gflag = 0;
            if(arr[i] == 1) {
                for(j = i+1; j<n; j++) {
                    if(arr[j] == 1) {
                        gflag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if(count<5 && gflag == 1) {
                    cout<<"NO\n";
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(flag == 0)
        cout<<"YES\n";
    }
return 0;
}
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SIGEMT** It is the emulator trap. It results from certain some unimplemented instructions (i.e you are trying to give a instruction which is not implemented in GNU library) which might be emulated in software, or the operating system’s failure to properly emulate them.

for memory space issue there was a mentioned hack on codechef blog, try to declare your variables before the main() function, so you will get a global variable declared on the heap.

https://discuss.codechef.com/t/why-do-i-get-run-time-error-sigemt/15957

Comment: thanks a lot! declaring variables globally did really work.

Comment: you'r welcome, but remember,bro ,it's not recommended to have a global variable without need

Comment: I understand but is there some other way to resolve this issue?

Comment: maybe, but i'm don't know till know, unfortunately, but promise to update in the comments here, if i catch up with better solution.